# Scraping Data Off National Vulnerbility Database: can't figure out clicking on a button (Mechanize+Python)

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to scrape some data off National Vulnerbability Database (http://web.nvd.nist.gov). What I want to do is enter a search term, which brings me the first 20 results, scrape that data. then I want to click "next 20" until I traversed all results.

I am able to successfully submit search terms, but clicking "next 20" is not working at all.

Tools I am using Python + Mechanize

Here is my code:

```
# Browser
b = mechanize.Browser()

# The URL to this service
URL = 'http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search'
Search = ['Linux', 'Mac OS X', 'Windows']

def searchDB():
    SearchCounter=0
    for i in Search:
        # Load the page
        read = b.open(URL)
        # Select the form
        b.select_form(nr=0)
        # Fill out the search form
        b['vulnSearchForm:text'] = Search[int(SearchCounter)] 
        b.submit('vulnSearchForm:j_id120')
        result=b.response().read()
        file=open(Search[SearchCounter]+".txt","w")
        file.write(result)

        '''Here is where the problem is. vulnResultsForm:j_id116 is value of the "next 20 button'''
        b.select_form(nr = 0)
        b.form.click('vulnResultsForm:j_id116')
        result=b.response().read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    searchDB()
```

Comment: There is some javascript in the form: <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="j_id7:j_id8" id="javax.faces.ViewState" name="javax.faces.ViewState"> Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring of `b.form.click`:

> Return request that would result from clicking on a control.
>
> The request object is a
>   urllib2.Request instance, which you
>   can pass to urllib2.urlopen (or
>   ClientCookie.urlopen).

So:

```
request = b.form.click('vulnResultsForm:j_id116')
b.open(request)
result = b.response().read()
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I am still getting the same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: @Rami: Works for me. You need to leave the `b.select_form` in there just before it. Oh, and we should actually use b.open, so it uses the cookies. Updated.

Comment: Seems like it works. Its scraping the third page and skipping the second. But thats an entirely different issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Rami: Interesting. I definitely got page 2 (items 21-40). Code here: http://pastebin.com/LCSr1GPH

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Mechanize outside of zope.testbrowser, whcih is based on Mechanize, so there may be differences, but here goes:

You click on the form...Try to get the button and click on the button instead. 
Something like this, I think:

```
form.find_control("j_id120").click()
```

Also:

```
b['vulnSearchForm:text'] = Search[int(SearchCounter)]
```

Can be replaced with

```
b['vulnSearchForm:text'] = i
```

As `i` will contain the value. Python is not javascript, loop variables are not numbers (unless you want them to be).

Comment: Lennart, thanks for your answer. But its not exactly working:   File "NVD-INFO219-Final-Project.py", line 42, in searchDB
    form.find_control("j_id120").click()
NameError: global name 'form' is not defined

Comment: Come on, you should be able to figure *that* one out yourself. The code was an example, not a tried solution, If you want that you need to pay me. :)

Comment: LOL, I wanna learn. I mistook it as real not an example. I just have been scratching my head on this for at least 5 hours, too jaded.